# masonjs random images in grid

Tags: jquery, random, masonry

I would like to achieve, that all my images are randomly outputted. I use this - https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason - plugin which works great for my purposes. But now I am trying a random output. 
This is how I am using it:

```
$(".imageGrid").mason({
            itemSelector: ".box",
            ratio: 1.575,
            sizes: [
                [1,1]
            ],
            columns: [
                [0,315,1],
                [315,630,2],
                [630,945,3],
                [945,1260,4],
                [1260,1575,5],
                [1575,1890,6]
            ],
            filler: {
                itemSelector: '.fillerBox',
                filler_class: 'custom_filler'
            },
            layout: 'fluid',
            gutter: 0
        });
```

Maybe anybody has a hint for me.

Answer (score 1):

maker of the plugin here. If you want to randomize your images, you may want to render them in a random order in the dom before mason does its thing, as well as randomize your filler content.

Your filler content should be placed randomly, but everything else is going to be dependent on where you place the dom elements, as in their order.